# How to perform a query in django that selects all projects where I am a team member of?

Tags: python, django, pinax

I have the concept of a team in my django app.

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    #snip
    team_members = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

I would like to fetch all teams the currently logged in user is member of. Something along the lines of

```
Team.objects.all().filter(request.user.id__in = team_members.all())
```

This obvious doesn't work. Does anyone have some suggestions on how to do such query without going directly to sql? I did look at [the django documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/ref/models/querysets/) of "in" queries, but I couldn't find my use case there.

Many thanks!
Nick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `in` here, Django handles that automatically in a ManyToMany lookup.

Also, you need to understand that the database fields must always be on the *left* of the lookup, as they are actually handled as parameters to a function.

What you actually want is very simple:

```
Team.objects.filter(team_members=request.user)
```

or

```
request.user.team_set.all()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this tip, I must have missed this in the documentation, this is exactly what I need.